# focus on the next text box if KeyCode=.(DOT)

Tags: vb.net

I have 4 textboxes which are used to store IP Addresses. I want to automate the selection of the textboxes by inputting the .(DOT) character; I want also this character to be deleted right after having been input. I have been able to get the auto-selection functionality, but not the character deletion part. Here is my code:

```
   If e.KeyCode = Keys.OemPeriod Then

       TextBox2.Focus()
   End If
```

Comment: If your English is not too good, perhaps you should use an online translator; also I don't think that this has too much too do with writing clear text and code. The clearer is the problem, the quicker will come the solution.

Comment: Are you trying Keyup event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
       If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46 Then 'It does not matter how you select the character
            TextBox2.Focus()
            e.Handled = True 'To avoid the character to be written (i.e., delete the DOT)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
       If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46 Then
            TextBox3.Focus()
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46 Then
            TextBox4.Focus()
            e.Handled = True 
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry Bu It Did'nt Clear DOT in text box!

Comment: set your textbox.maxlength=3  and then  you try

Comment: then you use "." in you code and IP not exceed 3 that make sense

Comment: where i am using Key_Up

Comment: After fixing some misunderstandings, this code does deliver what the OP is requesting: right after inputting "." in any textbox, this character is deleted right away (e.Handled = true) and the focus goes to the "next textbox" (from TextBox1 to TextBox2, etc.). Senthikumar has preferred to rely on KeyPress, but it would be also possible to use other events (e.g., KeyUp).